# Changes made on DB server with putty

Tags: oracle, command, putty, history

I am working from putty console and administer oracle database. How can I see all changes made on that server with putty? There are two of us who administer database, so I want to see all changes (commands which are used) that my coleague made on DB server with putty. I can not see them with history command, because it list just my own commands.

Is there any way to see them with dba priviledges (without connect as that other dba) i have, and what are steps to set up database on server for that?

Comment: could you please make it more clear - do you want the history on the server level (OS shell commands) or the history in the DB (sqlplus or whatever)?

Comment: And if you're talking about the shell commands, are you staying as your two separate OS users, each in the dba group(?); or are you su'ing to a common account (e.g. oracle) to make changes?

Comment: I am talking about shell comamads. And yes, talking about same oracle server username. But, changes are made with two different sessions, and for exaple, i know that anoter dba worked with expdp commands, but when i do history, it acctually list just my own commands i  used before.

Comment: Which shell, and which OS? Does your profile define a session-specific history file? Are you both logged in simultaneously? This might belong on a different site anyway. It's nothing to do with PuTTY or Oracle, or programming.

Comment: log all your session output

Comment: I logged all activities from putty, but i can see only mine activities. No, we are not working simultaneously, when he quits session in putty, and when I connect with same credentials on Linux Oracle servere, i can not see what other admin was doing on...I can only see all my changes and commands...